# How to remove key/value from reagent atom vector?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I have a reagent atom which consists a vector of key/value maps.

How can I remove a key/value pair with certain key value which happens to be UUID? I have tried:

(swap! state/items (dissoc @state/items id))

but I get:

core.cljs:270 Uncaught Error: No protocol method IMap.-dissoc defined for type cljs.core/LazySeq: ({:id #uuid "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214", :description "foo bar"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `remove`. So this should help:

```
(def data  [{:id "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214" :description "Foo"} {:id "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214" :description "Bar"}] )
(remove #(= (:id %) "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214") data)
;; => ()
```

The `swap!` function takes the old value and returns the updated value. So `data` from above will be the old value. Your function you pass to `swap!` will thus look like this:

```
(fn [old]
  (remove #(= (:id %) "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214") old))
```

Comment: My data is like this:

[{:id "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214" :description "Foo"} {:id "e1f9341f-bc02-4c17-a594-b9b5ede72214" :description "Bar"}]

So my need is to remove a map with a certain :id.